# running psql command in a java program

Tags: java, postgresql, psql

I have a requirement where using java code I need to create/delete/alter postgres tables.

I have written a program as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psql -U postgres -d testdb -h localhost -p 5433 -f D:\test.sql");
    }
```

test.sql file looks like below,

```
Create TABLE MyTable1
(
    VersionNumber VARCHAR(32) NOT NUll
);

Create TABLE MyTable2
(
    VersionNumber VARCHAR(32) NOT NUll
);

Create TABLE MyTable3
(
    VersionNumber VARCHAR(32) NOT NUll
);
```

**problem:**

If I run the same psql command:

```
psql -U postgres -d testdb -h localhost -p 5433 -f D:\test.sql
```

in command line, it asks for password and the tables get created.

But in java program, there is not provision to provide password. Please let me know on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [connection URL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) instead:

```
psql -f d:\test.sql postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5433/testdb
```

Comment: i am using postgres 10.5 version. is that fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be better to actually use JDBC to connect to the database and run your SQL statements.  If you're set on using command-line psql, you can use `PGPASSWORD` environment variable to set the password:

```
String command = "psql -U postgres -d testdb -h localhost -p 5433 -f D:\test.sql";
String[] envVars = { "PGPASSWORD=yourpassword" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, envVars);
```

You can read the password from the `stdin` if necessary.  But, again, it's better to do this over JDBC.

Comment: Sorry.. This doesnt work. if i set PGPASSWORD directly as system variable, then it works. If i remove the entry from system variables and try to use your approach, it doesnt work. Can you please check the same from your side also once.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072336/11714800)
and using Java-code launch of psql at Windows OS
and using [ProcessBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/run-shell-command-in-java#ProcessBuilder)
**following slight modification works for me**:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    String connUrl = "postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname";
    String sqlFileToProcess = "--file=Disk:\\path\\to\\file.sql";
    builder.command("psql.exe", sqlFileToProcess, connUrl);
    builder.directory(new File("Disk:\\Path\\to\\psql\\containing\\folder"));
    Process process = builder.start();
    int exitCode = 0;
    try {
         exitCode = process.waitFor();
         int len;
         if ((len = process.getErrorStream().available()) > 0) {
             byte[] buf = new byte[len];
             process.getErrorStream().read(buf);
             System.err.println("Command error:\t\""+new String(buf)+"\"");
         }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
   assert exitCode == 0;
```

Don`t know why, but if:

```
-f Disk:\\path\\to\\file.sql
```

as argument in Java-code throws:

```
Command error:  "unrecognized win32 error code: 123 psql: error:  Disk:/path/to/file.sql: Invalid argument
"
```

(pay attention to redirection of slashes and backslashes in otput and input)